# Separate fields by comma and quotes in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to separate this csv file into a 2D list. The problem with my code currently is that it cuts off a few fields on lines with quotes in the data. There are quotes there to signify that the comma within is not part of the comma separation of fields and is actually part of the field. I posted the code, example data, and example output. You can see how the first output line skips a few fields compared to the rest because of the quotes. What do I need to do with the regular expression line? Thanks for any help in advance.

**Here's a cut of the code:**

```
import sys
import re
import time

# get the date
date = time.strftime("%x")


# function for reading in each line of file
# returns array of each line
def readIn(file):
    array = []
    for line in file:
        array.append(line)
    return array


def main():
    data = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
    template = open(sys.argv[2], "r")
    output = open(sys.argv[3], "w")

    finalL = []

    dataL = []
    dataL = readIn(data)

    templateL = []
    templateL = readIn(template)

    costY = 0
    dateStr = ""

    # split each line in the data by the comma unless there are quotes
    for i in range(0, len(dataL)):
        if '"' in dataL[i]:
            Pattern = re.compile(r'''((?:[^,"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')+)''')
            dataL[i] = Pattern.split(dataL[i])[1::2]
            for j in range(0, len(dataL[i])):
                dataL[i][j] = dataL[i][j].strip()
        else:       
            temp = dataL[i].strip().split(",")
            dataL[i] = temp
```

**Data example:**

```
OrgLevel3: ATHLET ,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,
Name,,,Calls,,Duration,Cost ($),,
,,,,,,,,
ATHLET Direct,,,"1,312 ",,62:58:18,130.62 ,,
,,,,,,,,
Grand Total for ATHLET:,,,"1,312 ",,62:58:18,130.62 ,,
,,,,,,,,
OrgLevel3: BOOK ,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,
Name,,,Calls,,Duration,Cost ($),,
,,,,,,,,
BOOK Direct,,,434 ,,14:59:18,28.09 ,,
,,,,,,,,
Grand Total for BOOK:,,,434 ,,14:59:18,28.09 ,,
,,,,,,,,
OrgLevel3: CARD ,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,
Name,,,Calls,,Duration,Cost ($),,
,,,,,,,,
CARD Direct,,,253 ,,09:02:54,14.30 ,,
,,,,,,,,
Grand Total for CARD:,,,253 ,,09:02:54,14.30 ,,
```

**Example output:**

```
['Grand Total for ATHLET:', '"1,312 "', '62:58:18', '130.62', '']
['Grand Total for BOOK:', '', '', '434 ', '', '14:59:18', '28.09 ', '', '']
['Grand Total for CARD:', '', '', '253 ', '', '09:02:54', '14.30 ', '', '']
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module?

Comment: Is your "Data Example" - the input data or the output data?

Comment: Yes the input data is the example data. And I was told not to use the csv module. I'm trying to use my current code but change the      Pattern = re.compile(r'''((?:[^,"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')+)''')

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to load a CSV into a list then your entire code to do so is:

```
import csv

with open(sys.argv[1]) as data:
    dataL = list(csv.reader(data))
```

If your example data is your input data, then it needs other work before hand..., eg:

```
dataL = [row for row in csv.reader(data) if row[0].startswith('Grand Total for')]
```

Comment: @matti same reason they haven't heard of the `csv` module? Besides - updated to show filtering on the "input"

Comment: I appreciate the csv module option, but I was told not to use csv. I am trying to make the Pattern = re.compile(r'''((?:[^,"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')+)''') line work for that case of the first line of example output

Comment: @italianmoses well - good luck with that one then... When asking questions in the future please consider stating constraints (of which that one seems completely arbitrary and pointless imho) upfront. Searching for "csv regular expression" brings up tons of stuff on how to not properly parse CSV files, but will most likely work in your case - have a look at http://www.kimgentes.com/worshiptech-web-tools-page/2008/10/14/regex-pattern-for-parsing-csv-files-with-embedded-commas-dou.html for instance