# Regex help needed for splitting CSV file

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have a section of code that needs to separate by commas, but not separated by commas inside quotes. I cannot use the csv module in python either. With the regex pattern I have, it works for everything except when there are multiple comma fields before the quotes, such as the ones I excerpted from the data. How should I manipulate the pattern of the regex or what should I add to it? Thanks

**CSV File:**

```
,,,,,,,,
Grand Total for ATHLET:,,,"1,312 ",,62:58:18,130.62 ,,
,,,,,,,,
Grand Total for SELF:,,,"6,589 ",,397:57:58,708.53 ,,
,,,,,,,,
```

**excerpt of DataL:**

```
[Grand Total for ATHLET:,,,"1,312 ",,62:58:18,130.62 ,,]
[Grand Total for SELF:,,,"6,589 ",,397:57:58,708.53 ,,]
```

**Regex code I currently have:**

```
Pattern = re.compile(r'''((?:[^,"']|"[^"]*"|'[^,]*'|'[^']*')+)''')
dataL[i] = Pattern.split(dataL[i])[1::2]
```

**Current output:**

```
['Grand Total for ATHLET:', '"1,312 "', '62:58:18', '130.62', '']
['Grand Total for SELF:', '"6,589 "', '397:57:58', '708.53', '']
```

**Wanted output:**

```
['Grand Total for ATHLET:', '', '', '"1,312 "', '62:58:18', '130.62', '']
['Grand Total for SELF:', '', '', '"6,589 "', '397:57:58', '708.53', '']
```

Comment: Please post the content of actual csv file.

Comment: I posted the CSV file, but that is all that dataL is. I just sorted out the important lines and made a list.

Comment: Wait, so you want to keep the quotes around `"1, 312 "`?  Those are almost certainly not informative, they're just there to protect the comma.

Comment: Using the built-in CSV module with `"` as a quote char and `,` as delimiter did not work ?

Comment: @ixe013 I cannot use the CSV module with this program.

Comment: @DSM They are important when writing to the output CSV file to make sure excel can read that field as a single field so it is not split.

Comment: @italianmoses: that's what "to protect the comma" means.  You don't need to save them because you know you need to add them at output time.  But I'm a little worried that you can't use the `csv` module-- I'm hoping that this is for an assignment?  If a coder working for me handed in code which used a regex to parse csv, I'd be tempted to ask them to hand in their keys along with it.

Comment: If you truly cannot use `csv`, how about first substituting each comma that you *do* find inside quotation marks with an indicator value?  `re.sub(r'"([^"]*),([^"]*)"', "\1__COMMA__\2")`  Then transform back after you're done splitting on commas.

Comment: @DSM Yes, it is for an assignment. I would love to use the CSV module if I could, but the assignment explicitly states otherwise. I need to edit the data in the fields before it is written at output and having extra fields because it split at the wrong comma will throw off the indexing of the list.

Comment: @DSM I'd be the same... but, at least this time the OP did mention they couldn't use the `csv` module... [unlike last time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123551/separate-fields-by-comma-and-quotes-in-python)

Comment: Please, do NOT mark the title as `[SOLVED]` like this. Just select the answer that fit the best to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
DataL = [ 
        '''Grand Total for ATHLET:,,,"1,312 ",,62:58:18,130.62 ,,''',
        '''Grand Total for SELF:,,,"6,589 ",,397:57:58,708.53 ,,'''
    ]   
Pattern = re.compile(r''',(?=[^"']*(?:(?:[^'"]*["'][^"']*){2})*$)''')
for (i, d) in enumerate(DataL):
    print Pattern.split(d)
```

*Produces:*

```
['Grand Total for ATHLET:', '', '', '"1,312 "', '', '62:58:18', '130.62 ', '', '']
['Grand Total for SELF:', '', '', '"6,589 "', '', '397:57:58', '708.53 ', '', '']
```

Comment: I tested that regex and it does not work. When it splits the data, nothing is being put back into the list.

Comment: Can you try this with the lines you get from the file? Or perhaps fix the excerpt from DataL above? The `Grand Total for ATHLET` part is not quoted, is it string?

Comment: Grand Total for ATHLET is not quoted. The only time something is quoted in the data is when there is a field that contains a comma in it.

Comment: But what is `[Grand Total for ATHLET:,,,"1,312 ",,62:58:18,130.62 ,,]`? is it a Python type? a list?

Comment: That is dataL[0]. dataL is a list that I put all the rows into. I am then splitting each index into a list as well to make a 2D list.

Comment: Thank you, after fiddling with the code a little more, the way I did my loop was the problem with using this regex. Thank you for the help.